# Implementing class imbalance algorithm in pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, knn

I have a dataset from which I want to create new synthetic samples. There are two parts of the problem.

Part 1: 5 Nearest neighbors are to be found out for each row. I want to find out neighbors in distributed way without using cartesian. How can I find euclidean distance of a row with the entire dataset i.e access rows present on other workers.

Part 2: After finding the neighbors, I will take each row and subtract it from its nearest neighbor taken randomly from any of the 5 neighbors we found in part 1, in a distributed way. The problem arises when I want to do this with rdd or dataframe. In rdd, map function takes only one row at a time and I cannot access its nearest neighbor even if I have the index of the neighbor. Similarly in an udf in a dataframe. Also, I don’t want to use filter on rdd or dataframe to find the nearest neighbor with known index as it is slow for a very huge dataset. Also, I cannot save the data of nearest neighbors on driver and broadcast it as it will also be of very big size.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry to be negative, but Part 1 you are asking how to do a cartesian without doing a cartesian. For Part 2 it is a simple join of original -> nn but that assumes you can afford a copy of the original RDD/dataframe. Can you create synthetic samples by adding some gaussian noise to your existing data? And/Or simply sample with replacement?

Comment: The nearest/most simple thing I can think of would be to find the nearest neighbours within partitions only. To achieve that you can use `rdd.mapPartitions(iterator => results)` which gives you an iterator over the records in that partition. You can then map each record to it's nearest neighbour of that partition only.

Comment: For part 1, I agree that cartesian needs to be done. But will it not increase the size of my data manyfold? I wanted to know is there any other way possible for the same. For part 2, I am using regular SMOTE algorithm which creates samples based on its nearest neighbor. Yes we can find neighbors within the partition itself but it is highly possible that it may not be the closest neighbor we wanted since we are looking only at a subset of the data in partition and this may ultimately affect the quality of my synthetic samples.

Comment: 'For Part 2 it is a simple join of original -> nn but that assumes you can afford a copy of the original RDD/dataframe.'
For this, I will have to find the neighbors from its index in data using filter and zipWithIndex. Again as I said, it is not so fast on a huge dataset which slows down my code to a large extent.

Comment: You're going to need to compromise on something, whether size of cluster, accuracy of results, or the amount of time you're willing to wait. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, I think so! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ImDarrenG I think I asked the correct question as solution is available without using cartesian. It would be helpful if you could remove the negative vote :)

Comment: I'm pleased you have solved it. I'm afraid it wasn't me that voted down. I wasn't trying to be negative with my comment, I was trying to help - it's just I was wrong :)

Comment: Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer with the help of @zero323 https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323

There is a function available in Spark 2.2.0 in pypsaprk.ml.feature as BucketedRandomProjectionLSH through which nearest neighbors can be calculated.
https://github.co2m/apache/spark/blob/d9f4ce6943c16a7e29f98e57c33acbfc0379b54d/python/pyspark/ml/feature.py#L197